# How to add dependency via arn in terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I have terraform code , to create few aws resources. for example . i create a s3 bucket and create another resource based on or which depends on this s3 resource. I know terraform will figure out that this new object resource is dependent on the first s3 bucket resource, as i have passed this => aws_s3_bucket.s3.id , to the new resource. I'm not sure if this is a arn or bucket name or some intrinsic id that terraform maintains. but is it possible to add such dependency by passing in arn or something else?

so say , i had a bucket name that is already created somewhere else, and I can simply pass its arn in my example below , so instead of aws_s3_bucket.s3.id , i can pass bucket name , as var.bucket name
will that work?

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
  bucket = "s3-bucket-name"
  acl    = "private"
  ...
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "init" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3.id
  key    = "bin.tar.gz"
  ....
}
```

I've tried passing this => aws_s3_bucket.s3.id, which works. but want to know if i can pass an arn

Comment: you can use a var to pass in the value instead of using an attribute from another resource but then you will lose the dependency, I.E if you changed that resource from code else where you would need to remember to update the value of your var in this code

Comment: In this code, the id attribute will just be a string value. You can pass a string from a var and it will still work but you will lose the niceness that in the current setup if you change something that replaces your bucker resource, terraform will automatically know to replace your bucket object too, or modify it with the details of the resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `aws_s3_bucket.s3.id` is actually the bucket name;
2. `aws_s3_bucket_object.init.bucket` expects a bucket name, passing a bucket ARN will result in an error;
3. `aws_s3_bucket_object.init.bucket` expects a string, it doesn't matter how you pass it there, so `var.bucket` will totally work as long as it's a valid string bucket name.